# expected token si no uso ;

Tags: javascript

La siguiente funcion me da error de unexpected token, pero si le agrego ; se quita el error...

¿Por que sucede esto?

```
function prueba(cid) {
  let moneyMap = [...cid].reverse().reduce((acc, [unit, amount]) => {
    acc[unit] = amount
    return acc
  } , {})
  
  [...cid].forEach(([unit, amount]) => {
    const unitValue = moneyMap[unit]
  })
}
```

La misma funcion con ; se elimina el error

```
function prueba(cid) {
  let moneyMap = [...cid].reverse().reduce((acc, [unit, amount]) => {
    acc[unit] = amount
    return acc
  } , {});
  
  [...cid].forEach(([unit, amount]) => {
    const unitValue = moneyMap[unit]
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Esto pasa porque en JavaScript algo como**:

```javascript
foo()
[...stuff].forEach(...)
```

**Lo toma como**:

```javascript
foo()[...stuff]
```

Y esto representa directamente un error de sintaxis ya que no abres ninguna llave u objeto valido para la función.

**Un ejemplo en el que puedes observarlo es**:

```js
const foo = () => {
  console.log('hello')
} 

foo()[]
```

En síntesis, al ejecutar la función creas un objeto, que no contiene ninguna propiedad que sea valida o directamente la sintaxis no es valida para el mismo.

**¿En donde podría funcionar esta estructura? Un ejemplo**:

```js
const foo = () => {
  return {
    love: 'lol'
  }
} 

foo()['love']

console.log(foo()['love'])
```

En este caso como el método retorna un objeto en el cual puedes utilizar este tipo de notación para obtener un valor, es totalmente valido.

Como en cualquier lenguaje con semicolons, estos sirven para indicarle al lenguaje cuando una linea termina, pues sino para el interprete esto es indiferente, de hecho por como está hecho javascript podrias abrir una llave en la linea uno y agregar contenido en la linea mil, seguirá siendo lo mismo y se ejecutará igual.

La solución está en simplemente usar semicolons, siempre hará tu código mucho mas limpio, espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo.